# JetBrains IntelliJ Gateway always download a new client when run Gitpod workspace

Tags: jetbrains-ide, gitpod, remote-development, jetbrains-gateway

I use Gitpod for remote development environments on my Macbook M1.

Why does the JetBrains gateway always download the JetBrainsClient every time I run a workspace after a few hours?

Here is the screenshot when downloading the client:

[image]

Can we prevent it and just use the downloaded JetBrainsClient? My internet bandwidth is not much, that's how I want it.